# How to convert string formatted date to date using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to parse a column's string values (e.g., `D20200910.T000000`) into a date format using pyspark.  I tried the following, but the results came back `null`:

```
select(to_date('ingest_id','DYYYYMMDD.THHMMSS')
```

Comment: Does the `T000000` part always have that text?

Comment: Q: What kind of format is "D20200910.T000000"?  It certainly isn't an ISO 8601 conformant date format, is it?  Just curious how you got it/where it came from...

Comment: @ernest, string values in this column always conform to the example I provided.

Comment: You're using the wrong patters, try `select(to_date('ingest_id',"'D'yyyyMMdd.'T'HHmmss")`

Comment: @ernest_k, that did the trick!  Out of curiosity, where can I find a reference/guide to the pattern values that correspond to the various date parts?

Comment: The specifiers are documented in in the `SimpleDateFormat` class javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html